# Can't connect to web app via nginx in docker container on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, nginx

I'm able to connect to the postgres instance with no issue but can't figure out why nothing happens when I try to access `localhost` or `http://192.168.72.151/` (Docker Desktop). I've included the relevant files below that I used for configuration. The nginx server seems to have started up correctly but honestly not 100% sure either. I don't see any activity in terminal when trying to connect as I do when I connect to the db.

docker compose file...

```
version: '3'

services:

  app-server:
    build: ./app-server
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app-server:/home/flask/app/web
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    links:
      - redis
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3

  nginx:
    build: nginx/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
    depends_on:
      - app-server

  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=appserver
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=appserver123
      - POSTGRES_DB=appserver
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
```

nginx.conf...

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log  /dev/stdout info;
error_log off;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /dev/stdout main;
    access_log off;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    server {
        listen 80;
        proxy_pass_header Server;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

            proxy_pass http://app-server:8000/;
        }
    }
}
```

This is docker  ps...

```
         Name                        Command               State                    Ports
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app-server_app-server_1   /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -- ...   Up      8000/tcp
app-server_app-server_2   /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -- ...   Up      8000/tcp
app-server_app-server_3   /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -- ...   Up      8000/tcp
app-server_nginx_1        /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:51651->80/tcp
app-server_nginx_2        /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:51652->80/tcp
app-server_nginx_3        /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:51650->80/tcp
app-server_postgres_1     docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp,:::5433->5432/tcp
app-server_redis_1        docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      6379/tcp
app-server_redis_2        docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      6379/tcp
app-server_redis_3        docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      6379/tcp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step to verify nginx is working is `docker exec` into *one of the instances*, and then `curl localhost` from there

From the host, you have three nginx containers, so you'd need to connect to *one of the ports* mentioned before `->80` shown in `docker ps` since those are the host ports

Otherwise, remove `mode: replicated, replicas: 3` from nginx (it is fine to leave it on the app-server, since you are making that be load-balanced... you probably dont need it on redis either) and just use one container port mapping of `80:80`, and then `http://localhost` should work

Comment: Thank you! I had cloned a github repo that had the docker stuff set up and figured I could use that to play around with. I thought it was weird that there were replicas for both redis and nginx but I didn't know enough yet to remove. Also had no idea that would be the reason I would be running into this issue. Thank you! I am finally able to connect after removing the replicas